# SQL: Conditional Passed Parameter variable within WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, variables, parameter-passing, where-clause

I am passing a parameter from a dropdownlist listitem value assigned 'PPNo'. The column in the sql table I'm wanting to select contains Yes/No values. Within an WHERE clause is it possible to select 'No' from the column where the passed parameter value is 'PPNo' and 'Yes' where the passed parameter value is 'PPYes'.

ie Can I write the following as an sql where statement?

```
where @PPvariable = 'PPNo' then PupilPremium='No'
```

The reason I am doing this is because the dropdownlist contains several elements that are Yes/No values and when I try to assign Yes and No and select an element the top element assigned either a Yes or No is selected and not the item I selected.

ie selecting Non-EAL from the below list results in Non-PP being selected.

```
PP
Non-PP <----this dropdown list item is selected
FSM
Non-FSM
EAL
Non-EAL <----this dropdown list item is clicked
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CASE:

```
CASE WHEN condition THEN result
  [WHEN ...]
  [ELSE result]
END

CASE WHEN VAR =1 THEN TRUE 
     WHEN VAR =2 THEN FALSE
END
```

You can also use CASE as the right hand side of an expression.

```
WHERE A = (CASE ...)
```

--dmg

Comment: thanks very much. The second part of your answer is what I was looking for.